# Wait for actions in TouchesEnded to complete before allowing more touch recognition - Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uitouch, touches

When a subview is touched it is moved to a specified place in the main view. Only **1** subview should be allowed to move at any given time. Problem is, if I touch two subviews at/nearly the same time (e.g., if user is using both thumbs on mobile device), *multiple* subviews move at the same time.

I thought if `touches == 1`, I wouldn't have this problem. 
I implemented a global `bool` but that doesn't fix it either.

Any tips? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I was able to fix half the problem with `ExclusiveTouch`: when two subviews are touched at the same time, only one moves. BUT, if there is a very short amount of time between the two touches, both subviews still move. Maybe it has to do with the .15-sec animation that moves the tiles? Like one starts before the other finishes?

```
    ...
    bool canTouch = true;
    ...

            public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
            {
                if (canTouch)
                {
                    canTouch = false;

                    base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

                    int touchesCount = (int)touches.Count;

                    if (touchesCount == 1)
                    {
                        UITouch myTouch = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;
                        UIView touchedView = myTouch.View;

                        // Move 1 touched view...
                        UIView.Animate(.15f,
                                               () => //animation
                                               {
                                                   touchedView.Center = 
                        emptySpot;
                                               },
                                               () => //completion
                                               {
                                                   emptySpot = thisCenter;
                                               });
                            }
                    }

                    canTouch = true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `yourView.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;`? 
Or disabling it from the View panel of the iOS Designer?

**Update**
For the fast-touch scenario, I would try to just trap the touch in the "upper" view without additional bool variables around your code.

```
public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    if (! ExclusiveTouch) 
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
}
```

UIViews are derived from UIResponders that forward the event (touch) to the responder chain through base(...)/super(...) in the overridden method. Not executing it for the exclusive view allows you to not forward the touch event.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the "Multiple Touch" checkbox is NOT checked in Main.storyboard. But, I just discovered there is an `exclusiveTouch` property... hmm..

Comment: Thanks again. Before I saw your updated suggestion I found a fix (I think). I stepped into/through each line of code with the debugger and found that canTouch was being set to true before the animation completed. So I put set canTouch = true inside the completion block, but that still didn't fix it. Finally, I set canTouch = true at the end of the animation block, with nothing inside the completion block, and it worked!(?)

Comment: I also tried out your updated suggestion, and that seems to work too! But I'm trying to understand HOW it works... Is my thinking correct here: Any touch that is on a view with Exclusive set to true enters the TouchesBegan method, but is ignored, therefore never reaching the TouchesEnded method? So any other touches anywhere in the app enter both the TouchesBegan & TouchesEnded methods?

Comment: Right, it's relative to the view. In this way, you prevent the touch event from the Exclusive view to "propagate" to lower views. I think you can get the same result (or better) with gesture recognizers!

Comment: Okay, do you mean "propagating" to lower views as in subviews? Or did you mean lower methods (TouchesBegan -> TouchesEnded)? I'll have to investigate gesture recognizers!

Comment: @JamesD.Schwartz I mean subviews, UIViews are derived from UIResponders that forward the event (touch) to the responder chain through base(...) in the overridden method. Not executing it for the exclusive view allows you to not forward the touch event. Now the answer is more complete, I hope is more clear

Answer (score 0):

The code in `canTouch = true;` will be executed immediately. So another touch(after a very short amount of time) will run into your `if()` statement because your `canTouch` is true now.

You can try to move this to completion block like:

```
() => //completion
{
    emptySpot = thisCenter;
    canTouch = true;
});
```

This will avoid other touches until this animation completed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried to set that bool to true in the completion block, but it still danced around that block, accepted other blocks before the animation could complete in the IF statment, and caused the problem. (??)

Comment: I mean *accepted other CLICKS (not blocks) into the IF statement, before the 1st click/animation was complete.